# Product barcode database for Singapore

Tags: data-request, products, barcodes, singapore

I am looking for database which has only Singapore items in it, any open source?

I have tried http://www.product-open-data.com, but to no avail.

Comment: What do you mean? Products PRODUCED in Singapore? Or products CONSUMED in Singapore?

Comment: Hi product consumed in singapore

Comment: In addition to POD, did you see outpan.com? http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/1554/1511

Comment: I need a mysql database file, but outpan does not have it.

Comment: Do you know what your use cased is? Maybe you just want to be able to identify any item that you, or your users, find in Singapore? In which case, would you mind some extra items in there? If you want “only items available in Singapore”, be aware that that list will change daily. So, what are you really looking for? Would “a list of all the products in the world” be too much?